# Getting Attribute value from database in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, authorization

How to retrieve list of permissions like below pattern?

```
[MyPermission(/*Get From DataBase*/)]
public ActionResult MyController()
{
   /**/

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this.
Attribute params are parsed at compile time and can only be static and const values. You could have code inside your custom attribute that calls into the database but you cannot pass a runtime value as an attribute parameter.